# Laravel Route not working with Wamp

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, routes, wamp, laravel

As the title states, I cannot get my site to redirect. I've made several attempts and am about to lose it.

My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I have this file placed in the www/Laravel/public folder as well as www directory

- **mod_rewrite is enabled**
- **AllowOverride is set to All**

My host file is as follows

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

**Here is the code for route contained in routes.php**

```
Route::get('authors', array('uses'=>'authors@index'));
```

I have a controller named authors.php, here is the code

```
class Authors_Controller extends Base_Controller {
public $restful = true;
public function get_index () {      
    return View::make('authors.index');}
}
```

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate. I'm about to blow my brains out. Please help me, I suck.

Comment: would you also mind to put what the system error outputs..

Comment: [Sun Mar 24 20:19:47 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: E:/wamp/www/Laravel/public/authors

Comment: check your view file if exist or the route in controller if its set correctly

Comment: Within the views folder I have the authors folder containg the index.

Comment: then check if the controller had called the right view..

Comment: Yeah, as far as I can tell it does. authors.index

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26833/discussion-between-kaii-and-spm)

Comment: What is the full URL you are using to access this route?

Comment: Sorry Kai, I wasn't able to get on chat. I think it has something to do with my htaccess file. The full URL is 'http://localhost/laravel/public/authors' within the application.php file I have the url set to 'http://localhost/laravel/public'

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention why I think it's my htaccess file. I input miscellaneous text within the htaccess file and the page didn't produce an error.

Comment: did you solve your problem? I have the same issue

Comment: I switched to xampp and that took care of it. For whatever reason I just couldn't get it to work with WAMP.

Comment: I see that you fixed it by changing software, well anyways....answer below

Answer (score 16):

If your laravel project is located in c:\wamp\laravel\ then you should be able to call
`http://localhost/laravel/public`
and see the default laravel welcome page or your own.

If thats the case, you have to check two thins:

1. Open your /app/config/app.php file and check that the value of url directs to your project.
   `'url'=>'http://localhost/laravel/`
2. Then open your .htaccess file and add the RewriteBase rule under the `RewriteEngine On` Line
   `RewriteBase /laravel/public/`

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. I used the solution above and it worked.

Apache rewrite_module must be enable in wamp as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup a virtual host pointing to your public directory...
in httpd.conf file.

Which can be found under the Apache menu...

Like so...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot c:\wamp\www\laravel\public
ServerName testing.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And your hosts file will reflect the url you choose...in this case...testing.com

```
127.0.0.1      testing.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Checking rewrite_module

Go to

- wamp icon
- Apache
- Apache modules
- check `rewrite_module`

And cheers , there you are after some headache

Comment: Please don't use the answer function for comments such as `Thanks` or `Me too`.

Answer (score 1):

Apache `rewrite_module` must be enabled in WAMP as well. It works with my wampserver.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it has a pretty easy solution. All you have to do just check the rewrite module in apache. Check the steps in image
[laravel problem with wamp server solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNVv3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create an index.php file in the root.

```
<?php
header("refresh: 0; http://localhost/appnamehere/public");
?>
```

If you have multiple sites under one domain, you may not be able to change your public webroot.

I had all the correct settings, and the right .htaccess files in the right place, but it would not redirect.  This fixed it for me.

This article was helpful in getting the wampserver/wampmanager links working.
[Project Links do not work on Wamp Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server)

**Post Script:**

If you add to the virtual host file at: 
E:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf 
and you create a virtual host that points to the public directory like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName Blog
    ServerAlias Blog
    DocumentRoot E:/wamp/www/Blog/public
    <Directory  "E:/wamp/www/Blog/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
```

and you add to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    ::1             localhost
    127.0.0.1       Blog
    ::1             Blog
```

You do not need the index.php file I suggested.  That file works if you are NOT creating a virtual host, both are not needed.  It's one or the other (although it does no harm to have it).

Answer (score -1):

They only right way to do this is to point web server to `public` directory. For example, if you've installed Laravel in `C:/xampp/htdocs/` directory, you need to use these settings:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/public"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/public">
```

Never edit `.htaccess` inside public folder. If you did this, you need to get original file back. Restart Apache after you make these changes.